# Python list of dictionaries concatenate based on specific value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I do have a list of dictionary

```
list_dict=[{'date':'24-01-2017','amount':12.0},{'date':'24-01-2017','amount':23.0},
{'date':'24-01-2017','amount':2.0},{'date':'25-01-2017','amount':10.0},{'date':'25-01-2017','amount':3.0},
{'date':'26-01-2017','amount':2.0}]
```

i need output like

```
new_dict=[{'total':27.0,[{'date':'24-01-2017','amount':12.0},{'date':'24-01-2017','amount':23.0},
{'date':'24-01-2017','amount':2.0},],[{'total':13.0,{'date':'25-01-2017','amount':10.0},{'date':'25-01-2017','amount':3.0}],[{'total':2.0,
{'date':'26-01-2017','amount':2.0}]]
```

how to do it in python ?

Comment: Please be more explicit on what you want to achieve and show us what you tried

Comment: Also, can you use pandas? it looks like the right tool for this

Answer (score 0):

Your output is incorrect as you want a dict that has a list inside it, but you can have something like this:

```
dates = list(set([item['date'] for item in list_dict]))
result = [[{'total': sum([item['amount'] for item in list_dict if item['date'] == date])}, [{k: v} for value in list_dict for k, v in value.items() if value['date'] == date]] for date in dates]
```

Result will look like this:

```
[{'total': 13.0}, [{'date': '25-01-2017'}, {'amount': 10.0}, {'date': '25-01-2017'}, {'amount': 3.0}]]
[{'total': 37.0}, [{'date': '24-01-2017'}, {'amount': 12.0}, {'date': '24-01-2017'}, {'amount': 23.0}, {'date': '24-01-2017'}, {'amount': 2.0}]]
[{'total': 2.0}, [{'date': '26-01-2017'}, {'amount': 2.0}]]
```